# How and where to include stdint.h type definitions in a header file?

Tags: c, header

If I want all of my *.c files that have proto.h included to use `int32_t` instead of `int` is it correct to write this into a header file called `proto.h`:

```
#ifndef PROTO_H_INCLUDED
#define PROTO_H_INCLUDED
#ifndef STDINT_H_INCLUDED
#define STDINT_H_INCLUDED
typedef int int32_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef size_t uint32_t;
#endif
```

and then include proto.h into all the *.c files that need this `typedef`?

Or should I include stdint.h into all of my *.c files?

Comment: Since you already have "definition" for uint32_t, you don't need to include `stdint.h`. The purpose of having stdint.h is not having to do all these `typdef`s. Does it not work? What is your real question?

Comment: Compiler-Nazi: where are the `;` in the code? Please post code that compiles in the future...

Comment: On rereading the first sentence, it appears that you either have a minor grammar error (which is OK) or that you want to change ints into int32_t without modifying the .c files (ie `typedef int32_t int;`) which is NOT OK!) Which way do you want the change to go?

Comment: i want that int become int32_t :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *correct*, but not the best solution for a number of reasons.

1. It requires extra work to curate this list of typedefs.  They're already in `stdint.h`.
2. Your typedefs aren't correct on some architectures, and you don't have any checks for that.   If someone sees `uint32_t`, they expect it to be a 32-bit unsigned int on any architecture; this would be a nasty bug to track down.
3. It's not clear to the users of your `proto.h` file that it includes stdint.h.  Some will say that you should include as few files as possible; in my opinion it's far more important to be clear.  Removing the `proto.h` inclusion in users' C files should only require removal of the references to functions declared in it, not adding an inclusion of stdint.h. You should add it to the `.c` file for clarity, and they'll want to do the same.
4. You've added extra include guards around your typedefs, these aren't necessary - stdint.h (and every other header you'll use) already contains include guards.

For these reasons, I would suggest that in any header file where you need definitions from another header (for example, to use macros or typedefs in function prototypes) you should structure your files as follows:

### `proto.h`

```
#ifndef PROTO_H_INCLUDED
#define PROTO_H_INCLUDED

// Typedefs for prototypes
#include <stdint.h>

unit32_t proto(int32_t *value, size_t length);

#endif
```

### `proto.c`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "proto.h"  // Forward declare functions in this file

unit32_t proto(uint32_t *value, size_t length)
{
    // Do something
}
```

### `main.c`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "proto.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint32_t values[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    uint32_t result;
    // Could do 'uint32_t result, values[] = { 1, 2, 3 };' (one line)
    // but this is better for clarity
    size_t len = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]);

    proto(values, len);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you better use `#include <stdint.h>` in this file and not every single file that uses this header.

Comment: My doubt is: if i include `stdint.h` every `int` will automatically become `int32_t` and every `size_t` will automatically become `uint32_t`?? :)

Comment: @polslinux: You obviously dont understand how typedefs work. The thing on the right becomes a new type that acts like the thing on the left. The thing on the left doesnt change.